# Transformar empaquetado comp-3 a numeros desde un .bin ebcdic

Tags: java, cobol

He logrado transformar un archivo .bin que viene de cobol, el texto del archivo es correcto, mas el archivo tiene campos que vienen compactados en comp-3 y en el mismo proceso me aparece con caracteres especiales, como puedo descompactar estos campos?

con este codigo he logrado leer los caracteres del .bin

```
        InputStreamReader isr;
        FileInputStream fis;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(
                    new File("C:\\Users\\USUARIO\\Downloads\\archivos_prueba\\archivo.bin"));
            isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, java.nio.charset.Charset.forName("CP037"));
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                    String linea;
                    
                    while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println("imprime la linea " + linea);
                    }

         catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
```

los caracteres aparecen bien, son correctos, mas los compactados no salen bien
alguien pudiera ayudarme a descompactar estos campos?

Answer (score 0):

El tipo de datos COMP-3 o también llamado "Packed Decimals", guarda los datos en formato BDC (binary coded decimal). Lo que hace BCD es que almacena números en formato DECIMAL, como cada número puede ir de 0 a 9, cabe en 4 bits (un nibble) de esta forma es capaz de guardar dos números en un solo byte.
 Así resulta que los números ocupan la mitad que si los guardáramos en un byte independiente.
 Por ejemplo, el número 32 lo guardaría como (0011 & 0010) resultando 00110010 = hex(32) = dec(50) el número 98 lo guardaría como (1001 & 1000) resultando 10011000 = hex(98) = dec(152).
 A eso has de añadirle que el último nibble (el menos significativo) se utiliza para el signo, de la siguiente forma: C (hex) para positivos, D (hex) para negativos y F (hex) para los que no tienen signo.
 Resulta entonces que el número 100 lo guardaría como 10 0C y el número 1000 como 01 00 0C.
Y los decimales ¿Donde se guardan?, pues en ningún sitio. Puesto que COMP-3 es un tipo de datos de cobol, este interpreta la posición del decimal, según como se haya declarado la variable.
Por ejemplo para el número 5000:
PIC  S999V99 se convertirá en 50,00 y PICS99999 en 5000
Por curiosidad, para saber el número de bytes que ocupa un número, bastaría con contar el número de dígitos de ese número, añadirle 1 por el signo y dividirlo por 2. Si hay resto, le añadimos 1. Ejemplo: para el número 1000 (01 00 0C) tomaríamos los 4 dígitos de 1000 más el signo serían 5, lo dividimos entre 2 y al resultado 2,5 al no ser entero le añadimos 1 con lo cual obtenemos 3 que son los bytes que ocuparía en COMP-3.
Después de todo esto, al tajo, ¿Como descompactar los campos?
Como los datos vienen de cobol y sabemos que los campos en cobol siempre tienen longitud fija, no tenemos que preocuparnos de cuantos bytes tiene un número, porque siempre tendrán los mismos. Así que lo primero que tienes que averiguar es cuantos bytes tiene cada campo. Si tienes acceso al código fuente del cobol, es sencillo, sino tendrás que mirar los registros que recibes en hexadecimal y buscar los patrones, ya sabes como funciona el tipo de datos.
Cuando obtengas el número, pasas cada byte o caracter a hexadecimal y partes en dos el número hexadecimal que obtengas y los vas concatenando hasta llegar al signo que según lo que sea lo pones o no. Para la coma decimal, lo mismo, averigua en qué posición está y siempre será la misma (si la hubiese). Luego conviertes el string que has ido concatenando en número y listo.
Espero haberme explicado bien, si tienes alguna duda ya dirás.